# extending module dictionary in cpython to return arbitrarily named objects

Tags: python, dictionary, module

Ive been tasked with implementing a python interface to our modelling software.
I apologize but this is my first exposure to python, so its a slow process.
Ive been working in CPython

Here's my problem.
If a user types:

a = model_123456  (for example),
I would like it to return the corresponding object.
The problem is these objects are dynamically created in the software.

I do not want to populate the globals() dict with potentially thousands of these objects,
if they're never accessed.

I do not want to implement it as a method eg:  a = getmodel(123456)
as we are striving for brevity, making most access through member attributes, not methods.

I've been investigating different solutions but none quite seem to be applicable or clear (eg "gettr on a module")

I *think* what I need to do is create a dictionary in my top level module, from which I can  override the getitem method?

If thats the case, Im having trouble figuring out how to do this in CPython.

eg:  m = PyModule_Create(&tdmodule)
Question 1: This already returns an object with tp_dict set.
How would I set/override this slot otherwise?

Question 2: How do I override the getitem function of a PyDict object in CPython (or create a dictionary with that similar attribute)?
Do I need to create a dictionary with a custom Mapping getsubscript method, or can I simply setattr on setitem?

Again my apologies if this question sounds confused and making lots of bad assumptions, it probably is.

Thanks for any clarification,
Rob.

Comment: It is a bit unclear. There are lots of ways of making a module not be a module, but it's hard to see how you intend to use it and where you need it to be.

Comment: The design is flawed. You should implement customised attribute lookup on a class rather than a module.

Comment: Also, I'd recommend implementing as much of this as possible in Python rather than C. Much easier that way.

Comment: The problem is that module's dict must be a `dict` (not just any mapping or even a subclass of dict). CPython calls `PyModule_GetDict` internally and expects it to return a dict (it uses `PyDict_xxx` functions like `PyDict_SetItem` on the returned value). `PyDict_SetItem` doesn't use `tp_as_mapping`, it uses dict's internal functions to insert the value. Your best option is therefore to abandon this idea and use an instance of your custom type instead. And unless you need to access a 3rd party C library, you should do that in pure Python.

Comment: Most of it is implemented in C, since mostly writing objects to directly interface with the C objects in our software. Once that base work is done, higher level python scripts will follow.

If I do the customised attribute lookup on a class rather than the module, it means our expressions will be somewhat longer everywhere.
Example, say I want time to return the current time object.

I can do time().frame  or project.time.frame  but not time.frame
Given that our previous scripting language would express this as just:  $F  we're already making things quite long, if that makes sense.

Comment: When I did something similar I used ctypes so that the entire interface was in Python. That saved a lot of effort.

Comment: Just change your imports from `import project` to `from project import time`.

Comment: Python in general tries to bind names as statically as possible (this is considered a feature because it makes it easier to track where things are defined; I understand your motivation but it will make definitions slightly harder for a reader to track down). If dynamic binding is important to you and you're not already set on Python you could try R, which is extremely flexible about how it binds names and can do what you're looking for. It's a very different language though so may not be worth switching just for that.